# Missing last string character when looping in PHP

Tags: php, string, loops

It seems very easy task to echo all elements from a string one by one. I was surprised when this code showed all but the last characters of the string:

```
function FirstReverse($str) {
    $arr='';
    $len=strlen($str);

    $i=0;
    while($i<$len+1)
    {
        echo $str[$i];
        echo "<hr />";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: your function is not complete. Or at least missing a `}`

Comment: You should use a for loop, code would be much clearer. `for($i = 0; $i < $len + 1; $i++) { ... }`

Comment: @Pietu1998 or `foreach ((array)$string as $char)`. Then `strlen()` can also be removed

Comment: Even better to use a foreach loop. No risk of being 'off by one'.

Comment: it should be `while($i<$len)`, and it works. Of course `foreach` would do.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe. I get all the characters of the string, and an extra blank between the last two HRs. See http://ideone.com/YhEuIV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try:**

```
function FirstReverse($str){
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
        echo $str[$i].'<hr/>';
    }
}
```

**Why:**

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++)
```

`$i` variable is announced and is equal to `0`.

The For loop continues until `$i<strlen($str)` (which works because `$i` starts on `0`, not `1`).

At the end of the For function, `$i` increases by one each time.

```
 echo $str[$i].'<hr/>';
```

This was just shorter than having two different `echo` commands - `.` joins two PHP strings.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I gave the example with while as when I used for it didn't work for me.